# Reset PHP array index to start from 0 after unset operation

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have an array

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Mercedes");
```

I wanted to remove first element "Volvo" and i use this

```
unset($cars[0]);
```

Now i have an array like this:

```
Array
(   
    [1] Bmw
    [2] Toyota
    [3] Mercedes
)
```

But i want to my array begins again with zero, to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] Bmw
    [1] Toyota
    [2] Mercedes
)
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to reset the array, after unset operation.

Note that, this method **will work for all the cases**, which include unsetting **any** index key from the array (beginning / middle / end).

> **array_values()** returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

Try ([**Rextester DEMO**](http://rextester.com/BNSDR34647)):

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Mercedes");
unset($cars[0]);
$cars = array_values($cars);
var_dump($cars); // check and display the array
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) instead that select special part of array

```
$newCars = array_slice($cars, 1)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/X7CZE)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to remove the first element from the array, the [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) function returns the first element and also reindexes the rest of the array.

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Mercedes");
$first_car = array_shift($cars);
var_dump($first_car);
// string(5) "Volvo"
var_dump($cars)
// array(3) {
//  [0] =>
//  string(3) "BMW"
//  [1] =>
//  string(6) "Toyota"
//  [2] =>
//  string(8) "Mercedes"
//}
```